# Deserialize xml to objects

Tags: c#, xml

I'm trying to deserialize xml to objects. But I keep getting this error:

> System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.Xml.dll
>   Additional information: XML-document (1, 1) contains an error.

This is the class I use for deserialisation

```
[XmlRoot("MRData")]
public class DriverData
{
    [XmlElement("series")]
    public string series { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("url")]
    public string url { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("limit")]
    public int limit { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("offset")]
    public int offset { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("total")]
    public int total { get; set; }
}


[XmlRoot("DriverTable")]
public class DriverTable
{
    [XmlElement("Driver")]
    public List<Driver> Drivers { get; set; }
}

public class Driver
{
    [XmlElement("driverId")]
    public string driverId { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("url")]
    public string url { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("GivenName")]
    public string GivenName { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("FamilyName")]
    public string FamilyName { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("DateOfBirth")]
    public DateTime DateOfBirth { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("Nationality")]
    public string Nationality { get; set; }

}
```

I am quite sure that the `Driver` and `DriverTable` are right, but maybe the error is in `DriverData`?

```
class RacingApiClient
{
    public ObservableCollection<DriverData> GetDrivers()
    {
        var url = "http://ergast.com/api/f1/drivers";

        ObservableCollection<DriverData> drivers = new ObservableCollection<DriverData>();

        // Syncronious comsumption
        var syncClient = new WebClient();
        var content = syncClient.DownloadString(url);

        XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(ObservableCollection<DriverData>));

        using (TextReader reader = new StringReader(url))
        {
            drivers = ((ObservableCollection<DriverData>)serializer.Deserialize(reader));
        }
        return drivers;
    }
}
```

This line throws the error:`drivers=((ObservableCollection<DriverData>)serializer.Deserialize(reader));`

The XML response is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="http://ergast.com/schemas/mrd-1.4.xsl"?>
<MRData xmlns="http://ergast.com/mrd/1.4" series="f1" url="http://ergast.com/api/f1/drivers" limit="30" offset="0" total="833">
    <DriverTable>
        <Driver driverId="abate" url="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carlo_Mario_Abate">
            <GivenName>Carlo</GivenName>
            <FamilyName>Abate</FamilyName>
            <DateOfBirth>1932-07-10</DateOfBirth>
            <Nationality>Italian</Nationality>
        </Driver>
        <Driver driverId="abecassis" url="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/George_Abecassis">
            <GivenName>George</GivenName>
            <FamilyName>Abecassis</FamilyName>
            <DateOfBirth>1913-03-21</DateOfBirth>
            <Nationality>British</Nationality>
        </Driver>
        <Driver driverId="acheson" url="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kenny_Acheson">
            <GivenName>Kenny</GivenName>
            <FamilyName>Acheson</FamilyName>
            <DateOfBirth>1957-11-27</DateOfBirth>
            <Nationality>British</Nationality>
        </Driver>
        <Driver driverId="adams" url="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Philippe_Adams">
            <GivenName>Philippe</GivenName>
            <FamilyName>Adams</FamilyName>
            <DateOfBirth>1960-11-19</DateOfBirth>
            <Nationality>Belgian</Nationality>
        </Driver>
        <Driver driverId="ader" url="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Walt_Ader">
            <GivenName>Walt</GivenName>
            <FamilyName>Ader</FamilyName>
            <DateOfBirth>1912-12-15</DateOfBirth>
            <Nationality>American</Nationality>
        </Driver>
        <Driver driverId="adolff" url="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kurt_Adolff">
            <GivenName>Kurt</GivenName>
            <FamilyName>Adolff</FamilyName>
            <DateOfBirth>1921-11-05</DateOfBirth>
            <Nationality>German</Nationality>
        </Driver>
        <Driver driverId="agabashian" url="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fred_Agabashian">
            <GivenName>Fred</GivenName>
            <FamilyName>Agabashian</FamilyName>
            <DateOfBirth>1913-08-21</DateOfBirth>
            <Nationality>American</Nationality>
        </Driver>
        <Driver driverId="ahrens" url="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kurt_Ahrens,_Jr.">
            <GivenName>Kurt</GivenName>
            <FamilyName>Ahrens</FamilyName>
            <DateOfBirth>1940-04-19</DateOfBirth>
            <Nationality>German</Nationality>
        </Driver>
        <Driver driverId="albers" code="ALB" url="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Christijan_Albers">
            <GivenName>Christijan</GivenName>
            <FamilyName>Albers</FamilyName>
            <DateOfBirth>1979-04-16</DateOfBirth>
            <Nationality>Dutch</Nationality>
        </Driver>
        <Driver driverId="alboreto" url="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Michele_Alboreto">
            <GivenName>Michele</GivenName>
            <FamilyName>Alboreto</FamilyName>
            <DateOfBirth>1956-12-23</DateOfBirth>
            <Nationality>Italian</Nationality>
        </Driver>
        <Driver driverId="alesi" url="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jean_Alesi">
            <GivenName>Jean</GivenName>
            <FamilyName>Alesi</FamilyName>
            <DateOfBirth>1964-06-11</DateOfBirth>
            <Nationality>French</Nationality>
        </Driver>
        <Driver driverId="alguersuari" code="ALG" url="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jaime_Alguersuari">
            <GivenName>Jaime</GivenName>
            <FamilyName>Alguersuari</FamilyName>
            <DateOfBirth>1990-03-23</DateOfBirth>
            <Nationality>Spanish</Nationality>
        </Driver>
        <Driver driverId="alliot" url="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Philippe_Alliot">
            <GivenName>Philippe</GivenName>
            <FamilyName>Alliot</FamilyName>
            <DateOfBirth>1954-07-27</DateOfBirth>
            <Nationality>French</Nationality>
        </Driver>
        <Driver driverId="allison" url="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cliff_Allison">
            <GivenName>Cliff</GivenName>
            <FamilyName>Allison</FamilyName>
            <DateOfBirth>1932-02-08</DateOfBirth>
            <Nationality>British</Nationality>
        </Driver>
        <Driver driverId="alonso" code="ALO" url="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fernando_Alonso">
            <PermanentNumber>14</PermanentNumber>
            <GivenName>Fernando</GivenName>
            <FamilyName>Alonso</FamilyName>
            <DateOfBirth>1981-07-29</DateOfBirth>
            <Nationality>Spanish</Nationality>
        </Driver>
        <Driver driverId="amati" url="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Giovanna_Amati">
            <GivenName>Giovanna</GivenName>
            <FamilyName>Amati</FamilyName>
            <DateOfBirth>1962-07-20</DateOfBirth>
            <Nationality>Italian</Nationality>
        </Driver>
        <Driver driverId="amick" url="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red_Amick">
            <GivenName>Red</GivenName>
            <FamilyName>Amick</FamilyName>
            <DateOfBirth>1929-01-19</DateOfBirth>
            <Nationality>American</Nationality>
        </Driver>
        <Driver driverId="george_amick" url="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/George_Amick">
            <GivenName>George</GivenName>
            <FamilyName>Amick</FamilyName>
            <DateOfBirth>1924-10-24</DateOfBirth>
            <Nationality>American</Nationality>
        </Driver>
        <Driver driverId="amon" url="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chris_Amon">
            <GivenName>Chris</GivenName>
            <FamilyName>Amon</FamilyName>
            <DateOfBirth>1943-07-20</DateOfBirth>
            <Nationality>New Zealander</Nationality>
        </Driver>
        <Driver driverId="anderson" url="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bob_Anderson_(racing_driver)">
            <GivenName>Bob</GivenName>
            <FamilyName>Anderson</FamilyName>
            <DateOfBirth>1931-05-19</DateOfBirth>
            <Nationality>British</Nationality>
        </Driver>
        <Driver driverId="andersson" url="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conny_Andersson">
            <GivenName>Conny</GivenName>
            <FamilyName>Andersson</FamilyName>
            <DateOfBirth>1939-12-28</DateOfBirth>
            <Nationality>Swedish</Nationality>
        </Driver>
        <Driver driverId="andretti" url="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Michael_Andretti">
            <GivenName>Michael</GivenName>
            <FamilyName>Andretti</FamilyName>
            <DateOfBirth>1962-10-02</DateOfBirth>
            <Nationality>American</Nationality>
        </Driver>
        <Driver driverId="mario_andretti" url="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mario_Andretti">
            <GivenName>Mario</GivenName>
            <FamilyName>Andretti</FamilyName>
            <DateOfBirth>1940-02-28</DateOfBirth>
            <Nationality>American</Nationality>
        </Driver>
        <Driver driverId="andrews" url="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Keith_Andrews_(driver)">
            <GivenName>Keith</GivenName>
            <FamilyName>Andrews</FamilyName>
            <DateOfBirth>1920-06-15</DateOfBirth>
            <Nationality>American</Nationality>
        </Driver>
        <Driver driverId="apicella" url="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marco_Apicella">
            <GivenName>Marco</GivenName>
            <FamilyName>Apicella</FamilyName>
            <DateOfBirth>1965-10-07</DateOfBirth>
            <Nationality>Italian</Nationality>
        </Driver>
        <Driver driverId="armi" url="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frank_Armi">
            <GivenName>Frank</GivenName>
            <FamilyName>Armi</FamilyName>
            <DateOfBirth>1918-10-12</DateOfBirth>
            <Nationality>American</Nationality>
        </Driver>
        <Driver driverId="arnold" url="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chuck_Arnold">
            <GivenName>Chuck</GivenName>
            <FamilyName>Arnold</FamilyName>
            <DateOfBirth>1926-05-30</DateOfBirth>
            <Nationality>American</Nationality>
        </Driver>
        <Driver driverId="arnoux" url="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ren%C3%A9_Arnoux">
            <GivenName>RenÃ©</GivenName>
            <FamilyName>Arnoux</FamilyName>
            <DateOfBirth>1948-07-04</DateOfBirth>
            <Nationality>French</Nationality>
        </Driver>
        <Driver driverId="arundell" url="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peter_Arundell">
            <GivenName>Peter</GivenName>
            <FamilyName>Arundell</FamilyName>
            <DateOfBirth>1933-11-08</DateOfBirth>
            <Nationality>British</Nationality>
        </Driver>
        <Driver driverId="ascari" url="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alberto_Ascari">
            <GivenName>Alberto</GivenName>
            <FamilyName>Ascari</FamilyName>
            <DateOfBirth>1918-07-13</DateOfBirth>
            <Nationality>Italian</Nationality>
        </Driver>
    </DriverTable>
</MRData>
```

How to fix the error, and return the ObservableCollection?

Comment: Is your XML document correct? It should begin with `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>`. Right now, it misses the opening `<`.

Comment: XmlDocument xml = new XmlDocument(); xml.loadXML( strXML);  // presto, your XML is in an object.  Now you can run XSL, schemas, xPath whatever you want.

Comment: @Glorfindel the opening `<` was a copy/paste error I editted it

Comment: @WilliamWalseth I already have the XML in `content`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a number of issues:

1. You are trying to deserialize a single `MRData` element into an `ObservableCollection<DriverData>`.  It isn't a colllection.  Create a serializer for the single object:

   ```
   XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(DriverData));
   ```
2. You have ignored the namespace for `MRData`, you need to change the `XmlRoot` attribute to include this:

   ```
   [XmlRoot("MRData", Namespace = "http://ergast.com/mrd/1.4")]
   ```
3. `DriverTable` is missing from your `DriverData` class definition.  You have also added `XmlElement` attributes to all other properties.  These are *attributes*, not *elements*, so should have `XmlAttribute` attributes.  The complete corrected definition is:

   ```
   [XmlRoot("MRData", Namespace = "http://ergast.com/mrd/1.4")]
   public class DriverData
   {
       [XmlAttribute("series")]
       public string series { get; set; }

       [XmlAttribute("url")]
       public string url { get; set; }

       [XmlAttribute("limit")]
       public int limit { get; set; }

       [XmlAttribute("offset")]
       public int offset { get; set; }

       [XmlAttribute("total")]
       public int total { get; set; }

       [XmlElement("DriverTable")]
       public DriverTable DriverTable { get; set; }
   }
   ```
4. Two properties on `Driver` similarly have `XmlElement` attributes instead of `XmlAttribute` attributes:

   ```
   [XmlAttribute("driverId")]
   public string driverId { get; set; }

   [XmlAttribute("url")]
   public string url { get; set; }
   ```
5. Your deserializer uses a `StringReader` that is reading `url`.  This is the URI and not your content.  This should be:

   ```
   using (TextReader reader = new StringReader(content))
   ```

See a working example here: https://dotnetfiddle.net/bkYr7Q